# Consecutive UIWebView load requests in viewdidload

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uiwebview

I know before hand that this is going to turn out to be a dumb question, but I'm new to the object world and IOS.  In trying to trouble shoot a problem I'm having with passing audio files to UIWebview where Safari is playing two files one after another rather than just the one I passed.  I created a single view app and in viewdidload, I added the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *audio1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource: @"WarrenWreck" withExtension:@"mp3"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *audioForSafari1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: audio1];

    [self.safari loadRequest: audioForSafari1];

// Now the second audio file

    NSURL *audio2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource: @"Sequim" withExtension:@"mp3"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *audioForSafari2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: audio2];

    [self.safari loadRequest: audioForSafari2];
}
```

It plays the second file only.  NSLog comments, not shown, do show it rolling through both sets of setting NSURL and load, but only the last audio plays.  I have an old procedural language background and maybe I'm expecting things to work differently.  Why does this execute only the second audio file?  I've swapped the audio file name in each and same behavior.  If I comment out one or the other, the uncommented plays.

Comment: Well, because, even if `safari` loaded the first request, the second is put, and then "erased" the first one... It's not a "queue" system. You should `loadRequest:` only when the first music stopped.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking, but at the same time I thought there would be a queuing control.  So I would have to use webViewDidFinishLoad to figure out when to play next file (no user input here)?  And in this case webViewDidFinishLoad would = all audio has played?